# Returning different objects at instantiation

Tags: python

When I am instantiating a particular class I have written, I give it a name and several properties as arguments to `__init__`. Given the name passed, my `__init__` tries to find a file on disk that applies to that name and instead of processing the other arguments passed it reads all those from the file. And if the file is not found, the arguments are used instead.

Now I wonder, if I wanted to use `pickle` to store the whole object instead of using my own routines for writing files, how would I accomplish the loading? I can't unpickle my object inside `__init__` because there the object has already been created, right?

One idea I have is to write a class method that I would use for instantiation instead which returns an unpickled object if it is stored on disk, otherwise it will make a new object with the passed parameters.

An other idea is to use `__new__` instead of a class method that will return an object, however I don't know if that is the intended use of `__new__`.

Are these ideas any good or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a factory function instead of doing this in `__init__`. Example:

```
class Foo(object):
    # whatever

def get_foo(path, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = pickle.load(open(path))
        if not isinstance(obj, Foo):
            raise TypeError, "%s does not contain a Foo" % path
        return obj
    except IOError as e:
        if e[0] == errno.ENOENT:
            return Foo(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise
```

Comment: +1: You forgot to say: don't do this in `__init__`.  Do it separately in a factory function.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like using a classmethod for this kind of thing as it separates the special-case logic from the 'standard' class initialisation logic. For example.

```
class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def load(cls, name, **kargs):
        try:
            state = state_from_file(name) ## your loading code
        except Exception:
            state = kargs
        return cls(name, **state)

    def __init__(self, name, food=None, **kargs):
        self.name = name
        self.food = food

d = MyClass(name='eric', food='spam & eggs')
d = MyClass.load(name='eric', food='spam & eggs')
```

As for how to persist your object state... I'm not really a fan of using pickle; No doubt it works but I find it easier to explicitly save your instance state using a format like json, yaml etc. Feels 'safer' in terms of platform compatibility, future proofing etc. No matter. If you adequately isolate your persistence code, you can swap it out easily enough.

Comment: I think fundamentally, this is the same as @larsmans answer with the exception that the 'factory' is moved into the class definition. I'm hard pushed to choose between them really.

Comment: Here's a distinction that I find useful:  A separate function can be easily extended as the class hierarchy gets more complex without touching any of the classes.  With a classmethod, then new features require rewriting one of the classes, leading the very small possibility of breaking the class hierarchy.  I generally avoid factory methods like this because of the small chance of future breakage during an enhancement.